# Computer not showing up in network (Samba and LDAP configuration)

Tags: networking, router, ldap, samba, openldap

For some reason I have not been able to pinpoint yet, going to `Network` on my Windows 7 computer, the Samba server does not show up.

I have configured [Samba with LDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-ldap.html) and managed to successfully complete all the steps.

Both computers are on the same workgroup and connected to the same router.

My question is, what determines whether or not this Samba server will show up as a computer on the network?

**Edit:** I know this the information I've provided is very limited, I'm just unsure of what I need to provide. Please request any information that would be useful and I'll post it right away.

Comment: Are all the subject systems on the same IP network/physical network segment?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: What is the actual IP configuration of all systems in question? As mfinni has noted, if they are on the same network, then NetBIOS can work (if enabled on all subject systems). Otherwise, it may be a matter of WINS or DNS when spanning across networks.

Comment: Since he says they're on the same router (which is probably also a small switch), they're probably on the same LAN. Worth checking, of course, but the terminology makes me think this is a home or SMB network.

Answer (score 1):

Name resolution. You need the Windows server to know about the name and IP of the Samba server.

Since a domain lives and dies by DNS, this stuff works automatically in a domain. So if you joined the workstation to a domain hosted by the Samba server, it would work.

With older version of Windows, you could be in a single subnet and a workgroup and just depend on NetBIOS to populate Network Neighborhood for you. I don't have much hands-on experience with Windows 7 and workgroups to know if you can even turn on NetBIOS (and it would need to be turned on in the Samba server, too.)